# Excel/ Access: StartTime, Duration

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have a set of data with the following headings:

Username; StartTime; Duration

I need to find some way to illustrate how many users are logged in at the same time (only if there is more than 1, list the usernames OR user count).

There seems to be information regarding if you want to check if a specific date falls within a start and end date, but I can't find something for my specific problem.

For example:

| User | StartTime | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UserA | 02/13/17 13:15 | 00:29:00 |
| UserB | 02/13/17 13:20 | 00:30:00 |

I should get the information out that UserA and UserB were using the service at the same time.

Comment: Do you mean which users were on the system at a particular time, say 13:30 (easy)? Or do you mean (from a larger dataset) which were the busiest times and which users were on at those times (more difficult)?

Comment: Define 'same time'. User A's 29 minutes could overlap any number of other users (hundreds?). If you want to know how many users for let's say each half-hour (fixed periods starting and ending on the half-hour) - that's 48 time periods for each day. Your sample shows 2 users start in the half-hour of 13:00 to 13:30.

Comment: @TomSharpe Which were the busiest, I feel like this is impossible to do.

Comment: @June7 There are only about 10 users (luckily). I was thinking about every 5 min, but this will still be a major set of data points, if going at increments of 5min.

Comment: Why do you have Excel tag?

Comment: Count of login starts within a designated period is simple (see my answer). If you want to count user for each 5 minutes they are logged on, that would be complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating how many started within defined time period shouldn't be too difficult. I will use 5-minute increments as example. Calculate each user start time rounded up to nearest multiple of 5. Here is a helper function to do that:

```
Public Function RoundUp(dblVal As Double, dblTo As Double) As Double
Dim lngTestValue As Long
Dim dblTestValue As Double
Dim dblDenominator As Double
dblDenominator = -1 * dblTo
dblTestValue = dblVal / dblDenominator
lngTestValue = Int(dblTestValue)
RoundUp = -1 * lngTestValue * dblTo
End Function
```

Build query:

```
SELECT DateValue([StartTime]) AS Dte, 
       RoundUp(Hour([StartTime])*60+Minute([StartTime]),5) AS Minutes, 
       Count(Table1.User) AS CountOfUser
FROM Table1
GROUP BY DateValue([StartTime]), RoundUp(Hour([StartTime])*60+Minute([StartTime]),5);
```

| Dte | Minutes | CountOfUser |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2/13/2017 | 795 | 1 |
| 2/13/2017 | 800 | 1 |

If you want to see user details, don't do aggregate query. Instead build a report and use its Sorting & Grouping features with aggregate calculation in textbox.